# How to hide field that is foreing key in serializer based on a statement

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my serializer

```
class SparkleTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    notifications = NotificationTemplateSerializer(source='notificationtemplate_set', many=True)
    rules = RuleTemplateSerializer(source='ruletemplate_set', many=True)   
    class Meta:
        model = SparkleTemplate
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'enabled', 'run_schedule', 'notifications', 'rules']
```

I need to show and hide "notifications" field which is foreign key as you can see, but  that need to happen if some variable is true or false.

This is how I tried to do it, by adding the code below to a serializer, but I guess it doesn't work cuz of the fields property in Meta

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
        show = NotificationTemplate._meta.get_field('show')
        rep = super(SparkleTemplateSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        if show is False:
         rep.pop('notifications', None)
        return rep
```

I also tried excluding "notifications" and creating another serializer, but that doesn't work cuz "notifications" has to be there, so I was getting errors. Thanks

EDIT 1:
SparklesTemplate model

```
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default="")
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False)
    # sparkle must determine just how often it should run.
    # a cron string is the most flexible way to determine the schedule
    run_schedule = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, default="*/15 * * * *",
                                    help_text="The cron formatted schedule that the notifications will trigger on.")


    # this will be appended to the end of the get visits query
    query_extra_arguments = models.CharField(max_length=256,
                                             blank=True,
                                             help_text="Extra arguments that will be added to the get visits query.")

    branch_owner = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, default=None, null=True, help_text="Dictates the visibility of the users.")
```

NotificationTemplate model:

```
    sparkle = models.ForeignKey(
        SparkleTemplate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(
        NotificationClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    class_args = models.TextField(max_length=16384, default="{}", blank=False)
```

Also, I mixed up the direction of the foreign key in my post, it's the opposite.

EDIT 2
View.py

```
class SparkleTemplateView(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = SparkleTemplateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        
        return SparkleTemplate.objects.filter(branch_owner=user.branch)
```

Comment: Could you share your models?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano I did. Also, I'm not sure now if "pop" didn't work cuz "notifications" isn't originally in SparkleTemplate model

Comment: You want to remove `NotificationTemplate` instances from the representation in case _any_ of the instances `show` field is set to `False`? Or do you only want to display the `NotificationTemplate` instances with `show` being `True`?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano show is true by default, so NotifTemp will be shown when true, and it should be hidden when set to false through admin panel. And no, I only want to hide NotifTemplates that have show field set to false, but I can fix that with filter.

Comment: Can you show your view? You can use prefetch related on your view and provide a queryset for `NotificationTemplate` which will fetch only the objects where `show` is `True`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat added. It's quite simple though, and I didn't really understand your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`prefetch_related` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with a [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects), normally this is used to solve the N + 1 problem but another thing is allows is to provide a queryset for the prefetched object.

Hence you can modify your view as follows:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


class SparkleTemplateView(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = SparkleTemplateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        shown_notifications = NotificationTemplate.objects.filter(show=True)
        queryset = SparkleTemplate.objects.filter(
            branch_owner=user.branch
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('notificationtemplate_set', queryset=shown_notifications)
        )
        return queryset
```

Now you can skip modifying the serializers `to_representation` as you have already filtered to only show the required `NotificationTemplate` objects.

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the elements in the resulting dictionary from `to_representation()` by accessing the `show` attribute of each item in the `notifications`.

Depending on how you want the notifications to show, here are 2 options:

- Option-1: If you want to remove all `notifications` if at least 1 `show` is `False`
- Option-2:  If you only want to remove the `notifications` where `show` is `False`

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    rep = super().to_representation(obj)

    # Option 1: If you want to remove all notifications if at least 1 show is False
    # if any(notif["show"] is False for notif in rep["notifications"]):
    #     del rep['notifications']  # Or rep.pop('notifications')

    # Option 2: If you only want to remove the notifications where show is False
    rep["notifications"] = list(filter(lambda notif: notif["show"], rep["notifications"]))

    return rep
```

Comment: This threw a lot  of errors, same as when I completely removed "notification" field from fields in serializer

Comment: Perhaps you added both options? Could you try just with Option 2? I already updated my answer with the commented option 1 to avoid confusion as it seems too that option 2 is what's needed. Also, what is the error thrown?

Comment: No, no, I commented out the 1st one and just tried the 2nd one.

Comment: What error is thrown? I actually tried this on my machine with a minified version of your models and serializers and worked (related field `notifications` was correctly displayed with the `True` shows). Probably my configuration is lacking :)

Comment: 1st: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'lastframe'     2nd  raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key " ...) KeyError                                                   thanks for your help btw. The biggest problem might be that I didn't write this code, so something might be happening somewhere else without me seeing it

Comment: `lastframe` isn't present in any part of the pasted codes in the question. Perhaps the error is somewhere else? I'm not sure if it's directly caused by this changes because `lastframe` isn't even a field of those modes.

Comment: Yea, strange, I know. But that happens when I add this code. There are no errors without it. Who knows what's going in... I'll figure it out somehow. Thanks